# Blazor server JSRuntime.Confirm() is causing page reload / connection-reset on waiting 10 minutes

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side

I deployed a simple .NET Core 6 Blazor server app here https://epd-web.azurewebsites.net in Azure . A javascript confirm ( *JSRuntime.Confirm("Plesae select")*) will be prompted on clicking below buttton.

[image]

If you wait for more than 10 minutes and then respond to "OK" button, page reload link is appearing. i.e. connection lost already.

> This issue isn't happening in local.

I already added below middleware settings.

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
            {
                options.DetailedErrors = true;
                options.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            });


 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                // other settings go here
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options => options.WebSockets.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1)));
```

Comment: Don't use confirm for this it is a blocking method and causes the problem you see.

Comment: But we need user confirmation after submission validations whether to proceed or not. That why confirmation dialog. We need to block the flow and wait for user choise

Comment: You should not be using form submissions in Blazor, and any other type of confirmation can be achieved with a modal dialog

Comment: I am not submitting using Form. All API calls only. I need to block the code execution in middle and proceeding code execution after confirm shown will be based on confirmation dialog OK/Cancel choose. Custom Model dialog won't block the code execution flow i.e. dialog will be shown and then the code after the line of calling custom dialog will also be executed. Otherwise I need to re-arrange the code under custom dialog OK/Cancel buttons to block the code flow. Its an impacting task at this moment.

Comment: Your original question (which wasn't a question) was about using confirm - which is blocking and will cause timeouts. If you have new questions about alternative approaches - you should create new question(s)